# rosrun rviz failed in Groovy

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 by using "update manager", and in updated 12.04, I installed Groovy using commands "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full". There were not any errors during the installation. However, my entering "rosrun rviz rviz" in the terminal leads to:

```
[ INFO] [1357508126.785180749]: rviz version 1.9.18
[ INFO] [1357508126.785299200]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
ImportError: No module named rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
[librospack]: error while executing command
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  rospack could not find the rviz package containing rviz::Panel
Aborted (core dumped).
```

Any one who can help me out?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51566/rosrun-rviz-failed-in-groovy/) by [chenling34401](https://answers.ros.org/users/2274/chenling34401/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error says, check your rosdep version. It gets installed separately as python-rosdep.
See:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source

Not sure whether that will also help with the rviz problem.

EDIT: It is possible that there is a conflict with a previous version of rosdep installed via pip or easy_install. You should removed that one, if that's the case.

```
$ sudo pip uninstall rosdep
```

if that fails, you can fall back to:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep*
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chenling34401](https://answers.ros.org/users/2274/chenling34401/) on 2013-01-06**:
Thanks, as you suggested, I tried "sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-wstool build-essential", and rosdep was successfully installed. But the same problem remained. However, I tried installing ros fuerte and  "rosrun rviz rviz" worked well for fuerte. I am still struggled.

**Comment by [nickd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3862/nickd/) on 2013-01-07**:
i was getting the same error you were  and "sudo pip uninstall rosdep" then "sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-wstool build-essential" fixed it for me and "rosrun rviz rviz" works . I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and groovy.